# Android automation using appium fails to click the hamburger navigation button(randomly)

Tags: c#, android, automation, appium, specflow

I am writing automation test for android and trying to click the slideout button to open the navigation.

[image: Application screenshot]

I am using Appium and SpecFlow features.
What I tried to do is the following:

```
[Given(@"I press hamburger button")]
public void GivenIPressHumburgerButton()
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<AppiumWebElement> appiumWebElements = _driverInit.GetDriver().FindElements(By.ClassName("android.widget.ImageButton"));
    appiumWebElements[0].Click();
}
```

**Problem: This test sometimes fails, and some other times passes.**

**Question: Is there a better way to locate the hamburger button in automation tests and click it so it always passes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give a try by adding a few seconds of wait before clicking the hamburger button.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: It worked first time, I will keep testing it for more than once, since it used to work randomly and then get back to you again :)